# Closing cursors and exception

Tags: python, sql, database-cursor

What is the "correct" way to deal with exceptions in a code block using a SQL cursor ?
Is it necessary/recommended to close the cursor and the database? If so, what is the correct way to do it?

I use to do it like this:

```
    try:
        my_cursor = my_database.cursor(buffered=True)
        my_sql_query = "SELECT MY_FIELDS FROM MY_TABLE"
        my_cursor.execute(my_sql_query )
        my_selected_rows = my_cursor.fetchall()
        
        for rows in my_selected_rows :
            do_something
        my_cursor.close()
        my_database.close()
        
    except Exception as e:        
        if my_cursor is not None:
            my_cursor.close()
        if my_database is not None:
            my_database.close()
```

In PyCharm, this code rise two warnings "Local variable might be referenced before assignment" for the line `if my_cursor is not None` and `if my_database is not None`

Comment: It's not a bad idea to close the cursor to free server resources.

Comment: `my_database` isn't even set in the shown code. The second warning makes no sense.

Comment: @Michael Butscher  The database is set before in the code. I didn't mention it because it's not the point of my question

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is the use of [contextlib.ExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack):

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    my_database = connect(...)
    stack.callback(my_database.close)
    my_cursor = my_database.cursor(buffered=True)
    stack.callback(my_cursor.close)
    .
    .
    .
```

As soon as the with-block is left (regardless if regularly or by exception) the `close` methods are called if the creation of db connection or cursor didn't raise an exception themselves.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're very close. However I assume that you should not expect Exception to be raised while creating database or a cursor, so those should be created before `try - except`. This way you won't get warnings that you've mentioned.
Back to the first question: the most secure approach is to always close both - cursor and connection - after you don't need them anymore.

Comment: "you should not expect Exception to be raised while creating database or a cursor". Really? I mean what if the database is badly set, would the cursor throw an exception?